# Easiest way to create a object that can take custom atttributes in python

Tags: python, dynamic, attributes

In python, instances of classes can have custom attributes set dynamically:

```
class A(object):
    pass

a=A()
a.x=1
```

This, however, doesn't work if you instantiate `object`

```
object().x=1 
#raises AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'x'
```

`object` has no `__dict__` attribute to store the custom attributes, so this doesn't work.

What's the easiest way to create a object where we can dynamically create custom attributes?

Comment: What's wrong with `a=A()` approach?

Comment: I don't get your problem. What exactly do you need? Your method is completely fine as it is.

Comment: @aIKid,alko I guess there's no problem with it, I was just curious if there was a easier way. Also, creating a custom class for what will be totally unrelated instances feels "wrong" from a OOP perspective - someone reading the code will think the instances are related when they're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick I've seen is:

```
x = lambda: magic
x.foo = 1
x.bar = 2
```

Which takes advantage of the fact functions have a `__dict__`

Comment: Nice! It never occurred to me to use a function

Answer (score 3):

Seems that your example with creating an "empty" class is the fastest solution.

Nevertheless I wouldn't recommend doing this. When you access the attribute 'x' before assignment, you'll get an AttributeError. In other places inside your application you will not be able to determine how to handle objects, because you can't use type-checking to determine the object's features (attributes etc.). You'll always have to use `hasattr()` etc.

If you still want an object accepting any attribute names, consider overriding `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` in your class. See this python doc: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__

Comment: +1 fair warnings. The reason I want to do this is because I need to mock objects, and I can't instantiate the original class (the original objects are created using C). Overriding `__getattr__` would be a bit of overkill, since I just need to make sure two attributes exist, and I create them immediately after creating the mock object

Comment: In that case you could use your `class A(object): pass` approach. Or you create a class creating the attributes you need in its `__init__()`.

Comment: use this for moking objects http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html

Answer (score 1):

The way you propose in your question is generally fine (and often used) for mocking.  However, if you'd doing it a lot, you might want to look at the [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) library.  In Python3, its part of the stdlib (`import unittest.mock`)